# Are there any travel experiences in Australia that offer aboriginal (or Torres Strait) “cultural immersion”?

Tags: australia, culture, languages, indigenous-peoples

I am wondering if it's possible for a traveller in Australia to immerse in aboriginal culture, or Torres Strait Islander culture.

By "immerse" I mean stay in a traditional aboriginal area where people speak the language on an everyday basis and generally live to some degree or other in a traditional way. Maybe including staying with a family and being taught some traditional skills or otherwise participating in daily life.

I'm from Australia and work in tourism and I think it's safe to say most Aussies would have no idea if you can do this. But it's a big country and we're pretty ignorant of our native culture.

For me the language aspect is important. I do know the most actively maintained indigenous languages in Australia are in **Central Australia** (Pitjantjara, Arrernte, Warlpiri) and **Torres Strait** (Kala Lagaw Ya). I also believe that traditional culture and language is practiced in **Arnhem Land** by the Yolngu people. But I have no idea about the state of tourism in those areas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ada Parry of Woodygupildiyerr, the Cultural Education Coordinator for NTGPE - had a cultural Aboriginal immersion course offered in July of this year.  7 people were invited to come and stay with his family in her cultural home for 5 days.

I'd suggest that would be a great place to start - if the program was successful, Ada may well be running more, and may even be aware of other similar projects happening within Australia.

[The project ran from July 4th to July 8th of this year](http://ntgpe.org/aboutus/documents/091008_mrk_Cultural%20Immersion%20Program%20Brochure.pdf).

Comment: You get the points Mark not because you need them but because the one you found was specifically about immersion even though I couldn't find any mention of whether the people maintain their traditional language or not.

Comment: sweet, I aim to please :)

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of "centers" in Australia that offer an aboriginal cultural immersion program. Here is a list of some in the North:

http://www.frommers.com/destinations/australia/0212020858.html

For points further south (.e.g. New South Wales), there is the Edmund Rice Center.

http://www.erc.org.au/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=124

Comment: This seems to be a good start but none of the Frommers ones mention anything about the language aspect and the Edmund Rice Center one makes it sound like the language isn't use on a day to day basis. (I don't think any aboriginal languages are in active use in NSW but I'd love to be wrong!)